# How to remote debug software after automated releasing software

Tags: remote-debugging, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm currently releasing my asp.net web pages using a vsts release plan.

- The build is executed using an on-premise build controller.
- Within the build definition a step is added for publishing symbols (using the default settings)

What do I have to do to remotely debug this application? I can attach my debugger but I'm getting a message the breakpoint will not hit because no symbols have been loaded.

What do I have to do to get my symbols loaded?
(Where are my symbols saved, how do I expose them en how do I inform Visual Studio to get them from this specific location, can I do this for both Debug as well as Release version).

A link to some kind of reference/documentation is fine too. I can't find proper documentation of releasing using symbols.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably built the app in "Release" configuration. Try Debug configuration - this way it should be easier to connect to the app with the debugger. Needless to say, once you have ironed out the bugs, you should rebuild in Release so you can publish in production

Comment: Building the software in "Debug" mode requires the software to be redeployed. Normally production software is in "release" mode. Isn't there an option to debug "release" mode software ?

Comment: Yes, indeed that is the problem. Yet I have never managed to properly debug assemblies built in Release configuration. Maybe answer above will help you, though it never worked for me for production issues.

Answer (score 0):

With publish symbols default settings, the symbols will be source indexed but not published (Leave path to publish symbols argument blank).

You can share a folder and specify this shared folder path to Path To Publish Symbols argument.

To configure Visual Studio’s settings:

1. Open VS
2. Debug > Option > Debugging > General, enable source server support and allow source server for partial trust assemblies
3. Select Symbols
4. Add new symbol file location and specify cache directory.
   More information, you can refer to [Build: Index Sources & Publish Symbols](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/index-sources-publish-symbols) article.